# Grouping on specific state changes in time series data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, time-series

I have a table that is receiving rows each second, each second an activity state is delivered along with the timestamp. I need to group based on specific changes of state for instance when state goes from 6 to 0 and then all following 0s until state changes again.
The best way to explain this question would be an example:

### |TimeStamp | State|

|13:05:00  | 1     |
|13:05:05  | 0     |
|13:05:10  | 0     |
|13:05:15  | 6     |
|13:05:20  | 6     |
|13:05:25  | 0     |
|13:05:30  | 0     |
|13:05:35  | 6     |
|13:05:40  | 6     |
|13:05:45  | 0     |
|13:05:50  | 0     |

The result I would like to be able get from this table is 2 groups,(there are 2 changes of state from 6 to 0) grouping all of the 0 states that follow a state of 6 until the state changes again. <13:05:25,13:05:30>;<13:05:45,13:05:50>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    CREATE TABLE MyTable
    (
      [TimeStamp] NVARCHAR(10),
      [State] INT
    )

    INSERT INTO MyTable ([TimeStamp], [State])
    SELECT '13:05:00', 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '13:05:05', 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '13:05:10', 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '13:05:15', 6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '13:05:20', 6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '13:05:25', 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '13:05:30', 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '13:05:35', 6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '13:05:40', 6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '13:05:45', 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '13:05:50', 0
    GO

;WITH cte( [RowNum], [TimeStamp], [State]) AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TIMESTAMP), TIMESTAMP, STATE FROM MyTable
)
SELECT 
t2.TimeStamp AS [Start],
ISNULL
(
  (SELECT TimeStamp FROM cte WHERE RowNum = (SELECT TOP 1 RowNum FROM cte WHERE State <> 0 AND RowNum > t2.RowNum ORDER BY TimeStamp)-1)
  ,(SELECT MAX(TimeStamp) FROM cte)
) [End]
FROM cte t1
JOIN cte t2 ON t1.RowNum = t2.RowNum - 1
WHERE t1.State = 6 AND t2.State = 0
GO
```

Or [try in Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a75ae/34)

Comment: Great answer, covers the scope of what I'm working on right now. My answer doesn't actually fully answer the question :) Any insight on the execution time for this method, I'll be taking data @ 1Hz so 86400rows/day?

Comment: This is a very slow code. I do not see any simple way to improve performance. But you can speed up it be by changing db structure. For example, create triger, that records in special table only changes like 6->0 & 0->any number. Query on this special table will be more faster.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the question was clear enough :| so I approached it in another fashion as finding the first change from 6 to 0 was easy to do:

```
with x as (
  select *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Activity_Time)
  FROM WellData_Activity
  )
  Select x.Activity_Code, x.Activity_Time
  from x left outer join x as y
  on x.rn = y.rn + 1
  and x.Activity_Code <> y.Activity_Code
  where y.activity_code is not null
```

But the grouping of a series of activity_codes was more difficult to accomplish at the same time, so I used this to group them first (by the activity_code in chronological order) and then I can run the first query to return a row (which now returns start/end):

```
WITH periods AS (
SELECT
    *,
    grp = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Well_GUID        ORDER BY Activity_Time)
    - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Well_GUID, Activity_Code ORDER BY Activity_Time)
  FROM WellData_Activity
)
SELECT
  Well_GUID,
  date_from = MIN(Activity_Time),
  date_to   = MAX(Activity_Time),
  Activity_Code
FROM periods
GROUP BY
Well_GUID,
Activity_Code,
grp
ORDER BY
Well_GUID,
MIN(Activity_Time)
```